# How to design an experience so users can identify data in an application instead of leaving the app and then manually enter the info

Tags: usability, search, usability-engineering, addresses

Does anyone know if there any reliable 3rd party APIs in which store Hotel Name, Addresses, and phone numbers? The same goes for Airports. The reason why I ask this is because I am building an application in which the user has to select the nearest 4 hotels from the company and list name, address, and phone number, and rates. This is a cumbersome process because it requires users to leave the application and look on google for the nearest hotels and airports and then leave the application and write this info down on sheet of paper and manually enter all the hotel details back in the application. I am looking for a solution where users just have to enter zip code in the applicationof the company and based of that the nearest 10 hotels, with addresses, and phone numbers will be listed. With this, everything can be done internally in the app and and user will never have to leave the system. User selects 3 or 4 of the listed hotels in the app and selects those, and the data is automatically populated in the respective fields.

As far as a I'm concerned this is the most unusable method to capture data and leave the application and perform this task on the web.

Similarly to above, we are looking for data on airports. So users can just enter zip code and the nearest airports will populate.

Please let me know your thoughts on this. Any info would appreciated. We are desperately need any type of solution that does not require user leaving the application to locate this and then manually enter the data.

Answer (score 1):

**This sounds like a good use case for a third party API.**  Here are a few options:

- **[Expedia Affiliate Network](http://access.expedia.com/)** - May charge commission on booking, but have [a comprehensive API available](https://developer.ean.com/docs/).
- **[Wego Hotels API](http://www.wego.com/api/hotels)** - They offer a paid service.  They will return the hotel rates for you in the metadata, but it was unclear in
  the documentation if they can provide airport data as well.
- **[Google Places](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/)** - They allow searches of hotels and airports.  Free, although [the number of requests are limited and there are
  additional logo requirements](https://developers.google.com/places/policies#terms_of_use).  They don't have the hotel rate
  metadata you may require for the application, but could supplement
  your requests if another API lacks airport
  information.

There are others like [Hotwire](http://developer.hotwire.com/docs/read/Hotel_Deals_API) (mostly deals) and [HotelsBase](http://api.hotelsbase.org/) (again, lacking airports).  Consider these questions when picking a service:

1. **Do you want to book through the application?**  You will likely be setting up a business relationship with the provider and they will ask for a commission.
2. **Do you only want hotel rates with no booking?** Consider a paid service for the hotel rate information and supplement that with airport information from another service.  Rates are additional metadata that requires work from the provider to maintain accuracy.
3. **Can you avoid providing hotel rates?** A free API of commercial entities will return the needed information, but be aware of their terms of service.

Comment: we are looking just for hotel name, phone number, and address.

Comment: @ah123 - Consider trying Google Places.  It's free, and for verified accounts you can make up to 100,000 requests per 24 hour period.  [You can specifically search for hotels (lodging) and airports.](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Expedia API, it has extensive Hotel database to download, also including Airports. They also have nice responsive support.

[Here is my post on it and other (inferior) alternatives.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185961/travel-hotel-apis/15672534#15672534)

Sadly I could not find any comparable alternative, which would provide some healthy competition.